# In Clash of clans, What happens if storage is full and you have extra loot from multiplayer battle?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What happens in below scenario,

I have my gold storage size of 151,000 and its completely full. Then I attack some player from multiplayer battle and loot more gold? Where it will go? I am not able to see it in clan storage? Will it be deposited in later stage or it just get wasted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot store more than you receive, so yes, any extra resources you obtain via looting is wasted after you raid a player.

In this scenario, you also will not be able to collect resources from the collectors in question and they will instead accumulate in your collector's own storage (every collector has some storage).

This holds true for gold, elixir and dark elixir alike. If your collectors' storage are full, they will not produce any more resources until the resource is collected.

---

Extra info:

Similarly, extra resources obtained from war bonuses will also get lost if your clan castle storage is full at the time of receiving, so it is wise to collect your clan castle resources before a war ends if it is full or if the loot you receive will exceed the resource capacity of the clan castle.

Answer (score 4):

It just gets wasted so you should collect the resources from the clan castle beforehand where it will be transferred to your normal storage buildings.

Answer (score 2):

If your storages are full, there's literally no place for your loot to go when you raid, so you lose it.
Here are a few tips for managing that situation:

1. If it's your elixir storage that's full, you can queue expensive
   troops like PEKKA or drag, freeing up some space in your elixir
   storage, or go on a clan donation spree.
2. You could choose to forget about the loot and focus on raiding to get trophies.
3. Alternatively,
   you could choose to cool off on raiding and drop your town hall
   outside so someone can attack and give you shield, giving your base
   time in safety to find something to do with your resources before
   your next raid.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving more loot then you can carry is a complete waste.Same thing with trying to pick your resources in your CC from a war.Nothing will happen until part of the total is gone and you can pick from your stuff again

Answer (score 0):

yes, it goes waste as ur storages are already full.